# How do you specify the root context in your <web-app> tags in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jetty

I would like to specify the root context of my Java web application in my WAR file. How can I do this using valid `web-app` XML in a `web.xml` file?

Oh, yes I would like to do this in an application server agnostic way.

Answer (score 109):

This can't be done in an appserver agnostic way.  Context root isn't part of the standard web.xml file.  It's either specified when you deploy the app or in an appserver specific descriptor.

- Glassfish: [sun-web.xml](http://72.5.124.55/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html#bnaeb);
- JBoss: [jboss-web.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch9.chapt.html);
- Weblogic: [weblogic.xml](http://edocs.bea.com/wls/docs70/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1037343);
- Tomcat: [context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html);
- WebSphere: [ibm-web-ext.xml](http://orebmann.blogspot.fr/2015/02/set-context-root-for-web-application.html).

**Note:** the above applies to deploying WAR files.  EAR files are a different story and the context can be specified as part of the [application.xml deployment descriptor](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/content/J2EE-Deployment/chapter.html).

Comment: That link to Tomcat 4.0 documentation is at least 5 years old - anyone using Tomcats might want to check docs of later version

Comment: @mattb You're assuming everyone's using the latest version of Tomcat. People should refer to the documentation of the version they're using. As is the case with most software... :)

Comment: Can you at least specify to use nothing, ie localhost:8080/ versus localhost:8080/warname?

Comment: I havn't tested it, but after looking for the IBM WebSphere equivalent, I found the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484842/define-contextroot-inside-war-file   <--maybe someone could test that and add it to the list if it works

Comment: link for weblogic is broken. Could you add the new link please

Comment: I have Jboss application and in my case file `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` was missing. I solved problem by creating this file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
 <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
`

Comment: some links are broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in web.xml.

```xml
<env-entry>
    <description>web app</description>  
    <env-entry-name>appCxtRoot</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>       
    <env-entry-value>webapp-@context-root-value@</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```