# Define contextroot inside WAR file

Tags: deployment, command-line, websphere, war, contextroot

I have an automated deployment script to deploy multiple `WAR` files in `WAS 7`.
So, I would like to define `contextroot` inside the `WAR` file itself. It should automatically set to `" ... -contextroot xxxx ..."` from the file.

How do I do that? I think, I need to add something with `WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml`.
I dont know what to write in it.

Pls help, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create `WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml` with these contents:

```
<web-ext
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0"
>
  <context-root uri="/TestProject"/>
</web-ext>
```