# Migrating an Enterprise app from JBoss to WebSphere

Tags: java, jboss, websphere

I am trying to migrate an enterprise application from JBoss to Websphere 8.5. The application is configured with Spring MVC and tiles. The application is hosted in the server root of the JBoss Server, i.e. to access the application we just type `https://localhost/` in the browser.For this reason all the links and association in the applications are currently written as follows:

```
<link href="/resources/jQuery.js" .../>
...
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```

etc.

But in WebSphere the application needs to be in a context root viz. `https://localhost:9443/MigratedApplication`.

The problem is that all the links and resources mapped in the application now are inside `https://localhost:9443/MigratedApplication/resources` but they are still looked for in `https://localhost:9443/resources` resulting in errors on the application throughout.

Any ways to resolve the issue by configuration in WebSphere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484842/define-contextroot-inside-war-file

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I mentioned that the paths in the app are hard coded and even when I am changing the context root, the hard coded paths are still being searched in the root of the server...

Comment: you have to mention the context as /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have hardcoded paths in your application, so you have 2 choices:

- change the context root of the application on WebSphere to `/` as in JBoss (probably easier one, as doesnt require changes in application)
- change all links to relative ones (this should be done in the first place during application development to make it independent of context root)