# How to get Netbeans to deploy Java web app to Tomcat's Root (e.g /) instead of /MyProject?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

Netbeans always deploys the .war of my application to /MyProject on Tomcat. This means that I view them on `http://localhost:8084/MyProject` , and all links such as `/something` don't work as they point to `http://localhost:8084/something` rather than `http://localhost:8084/MyProject/something`. How can I get Netbeans to instead deploy the application to the root of Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be in your context.xml. The details of the configuration are here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html. Moreover, the context.xml is accessible within the /META-INF/context.xml path. I don't think that NetBeans will do that for you. We have to specify that ourselves, just like in GlassFish where I had to do the same thing in a glassfish-web.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when deploying an application, tomcat deploys `ApplicationName.war` as `/ApplicationName`.

Another thing to note is that an application called `ROOT` is served as the root (i.e. `/`).

Therefore the solution is fairly simple - deploy your warfile as `ROOT.war` and tomcat will automatically serve it as `/`·

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a context root of "/" but I don't believe this can be done in a platform independent way. See this question for more details:

[How do you specify the root context in your <web-app> tags in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be 4 years late, but I found an easier solution.

Go to `META-INF/context.xml` in your netbeans project and you should find something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myProject"/>
```

Change the `Context path` to:

```
<Context path="/"/>
```

This will deploy your project as root.