# JBoss REST WS application doesn't work when deployed as WAR file but works when expanded to a folder

Tags: web-services, jboss, war, web-deployment, resteasy

I am deploying an application on JBoss server (EAP-6.4.0, JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1).

I get a very strange behavior. Let's say the application is called `Engine.war`. The application implements a REST Web service server.

1. When I deploy the application by **copying** the `WAR` file to `c:\EAP-6.4.0\standalone\deployments\Engine.war` **file**, it is successfully deployed, but *doesn't work*.
2. When I deploy it by **unpacking**/extracting/exploding the content of the `WAR` file to `c:\EAP-6.4.0\standalone\deployments\Engine.war` **folder** and creating the `Engine.war.dodeploy` file, it is also deployed, but *does* work.

By *doesn't work* I mean that the server is complaining that

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 -
JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1
```

so the same behavior like if you misspell the URI.

All the web resources I have found state that *[these two deployment methods are just equivalent alternatives](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ExplodedDeployment)*, and for our other applications we do not observe any differences!

**Can you see any reason why in just this case it is matters if I unpack the `WAR` file or not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the solution. It's pretty stupid so I want to post it to prevent others from losing their time...

We have found that there *was* a difference in the naming. The name of the unpacked `WAR` file was not just `Engine.war` as I stated in my question (I did it as I believed it would hide all the irrelevant details). The actual name was `Engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`, but when I unpacked it I was lazy to write such a long name and I unpacked it to a folder named just `Engine.war`.

By default - unless specified explicitly otherwise - the application's root address is the same as the `WAR` file name, so for `Engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` it was `http://localhost:8080/Engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

However, we counted with address `http://localhost:8080/Engine` and it worked, as the Eclipse plugin always removed the version suffix from the unpacked folder and we did not realize that.

More detailed description here: http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/25/war-deployment-file-structure/.

So the whole "trick" was to add the proper `WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml` file with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/Engine</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

By the way, as another post says, you cannot do it in a server-agnostic way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/664089/2886891