# Getting error page for simple RESTful web service application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

This might be a pretty simple question, may be it's a duplicate (though I did not find any till now), but somehow I'm stuck and need to resolve it as soon as possible.

Basically, I am trying to make a simple RESTful web service using JAX-RS API. Somehow, I am unable to so. This is my first encounter with web services and I am pretty sure I am doing a silly mistake though after lot of googling I have failed to resolve it.

So, here is my project structure -

[image]

**MessageResource.java**

```
package com.rest.jersey.messenger.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>messenger</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST_Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.rest.jersey.messenger.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST_Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

URL I am hitting is : http://localhost:8090/messenger/webapi/messages

**Result:** I am getting error page -

```
HTTP Status 404 - /messenger/webapi/messages

type Status report
message /messenger/webapi/messages
description The requested resource is not available.
```

**Note:** I'm not using maven. I want to set-up the project manually. And, I am using port 8090 instead of 8080.

**[Edit]**

I am getting below warning while starting Tomcat server:

```
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Messenger' did not find a matching property.
```

I have tried below solution. Still same error.

```
Double click on your tomcat server. 
It will open the server configuration. 
Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox
```

Comment: This warning has nothing to do with the wrong url. I have the exact same warning and it works fine. Check here on what it means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `Context root`.
Try this url instead

```
http://localhost:8090/Messenger/webapi/messages
```

Basically your context root is the name of your web application. In this case it's `Messenger` instead of `messenger`. So the solution:

1. You can just change the name of your project and be done with it.
2. In order to change it via `web.xml` you have to follow vendor specific steps.
   [Check more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml)
3. If you want to change it via `eclipse` check this image. [Check more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)
   [image]

Comment: Still the same error. I am adding some more information. Hope it will be informative.

Comment: The warning you are getting has nothing to do with it. I'm getting exactly the same warning, but it still works. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Changed project name to `messenger` and tried `http://localhost:8090/messenger/webapi/messages`

Comment: Did you refactor or just rename? Did you refresh/rebuild/rerun? Try cleaning explicitly the project

Comment: I did `refactor`. I had tried using `Maven` as well and instead of getting `Got it!` I am getting same error. Something terribly wrong here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88947/discussion-between-alkis-and-kartic).