# How to set url path for particular JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I am working on one JSF project. but a very simple concept of J2ee is not clear to me. In web.xml one servlet has been defined.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now this line of piece of code says that when url like contextroot/faces/something then this servlet code will be executed. 
But when i run the login.jsf then its url in browser is looks like this 
"contextroot/login.jsf" not contextroot/faces/login.jsf

So my question is how can i set that on startup login.jsf should follow the contextroot/faces/login.jsf path.

Second can we set our own context-root for application. I am using web logic application server.

Comment: Did you add any welcome file as well in `web.xml`

Comment: You can set context root: http://stackoverflow.com/a/664089/3803447

Comment: Do you really have a physical `login.jsf` file? Isn't it actually `login.xhtml` or `login.jsp`?