# Configure the context path of a web app

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, contextpath

I am building a java web application using `Eclipse` and `Maven`. The app will run on either `jboss` (`wildfly`) or `tomcat`. I would like to configure the context path of my web application.

By default, eclipse sets the context path to be equal to the name of the eclipse project (seen in `project -> properties -> web project settings`). However, regardless of the context path shown there, when I deploy my war file, the name of the war file is used as the context path, not the setting in eclipse.

I would like to know how to configure the context path in the following three situations:

- When I run my web project in eclipse, using an embedded server in eclipse (such as tomcat or wildfly). It seems to be taking the project name in this case.
- When I build a war (with maven), and run this war file using an embedded server in eclipse. It seems to be taking the name of the war file.
- When I build a war and deploy it to an external servlet container (outside of eclipse). It also seems to be taking the war name as context path.

Is the context path chosen platform / eclipse / servlet container dependent? Has anybody documented the standard behavior of each container? Is there a way to configure/set the context path for all platforms and servlet containers, regardless of how and where the war is build/deployed, and more importantly, so the war name is NOT the same as the context path?

Comment: At least some answers you will find here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/664089/2365727

Comment: @michaldo I'm afraid the information there is a bit outdated (2009) but at least the concept that it cannot be done in a servlet-container agnostic way without using EAR files (instead of WAR files) is helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way so far to set the context-root of a WAR so that it is independent of the application server being used is : make it a part of an EAR and supply the context-root via `application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <display-name>EAR_NAME</display-name>
    <module id="Module_***********">
        <web>
            <web-uri>YourWeb.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>YourContextRoot</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>   
</application>
```

Even as of JAVA EE 6, the WAR's context-root has to be a part of either `jboss-web.xml` , `glassfish-web.xml` or similar server specific web deployment descriptor. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html#bnaeb) is an official example.

I could not find similar example for JAVA EE 7, but i really don't think this has changed. JEE7 was mostly about adding features around HTML5 and JSON.