# Add a directory to root of a webapp in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jetty

I have Spring + Angular APP.
I want to keep my directory structure as

ROOT

- WEB-INF
- UI-APP

  - index.html
  - css
  - js

But I don't want to access my application as domain/UI-APP.
I want UI-APP folder to be added / changed as ROOT. 
Using welcome file is not the solution because 
 
I don't want my Angular Project to be aware of UI-APP directory meaning I want all my js and html to use relative path. 
 
ie ( if i rename UI-APP to View then also I don't want to change my html and js files. )

Is it possible without container specific way.
All i can think of is creating a servlet to handle all request and return content of file from UI-APP directory or may be Spring Servlet Dispatcher already has an option for it.

I want it to be as generic as possible. 
Some Config in web.xml would be best. 
Config in dispatcher servlet xml would also be ok. 
tomcat, jetty specific configuration is the last resort.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the problem is in putting everything at the root instead of putting it in UI-APP. But anyway, here's how you map URLs to resources in Spring MVC: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: I am ok with keeping everything in root but i've seen most projects structured that way and in UI-App use absolute path.
I just don't want absolute path to be added in UI-APP,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml