# How to set the context root in java ee 7 application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've seen [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaeb/index.html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml) but I can't find the `sun-web.xml` anymore. I am going through the java ee 7 tutorial, specifically the [hello1](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/webapp003.htm#BNADX) application. I don't understand how the application knows that `/hello1` is the context root, I mean, I don't see it specified anywhere in the `web.xml` file under `/WEB-INF/web.xml`. How does glassfish know, and how can we change it to, perhaps, `/abc` for example.

Comment: *"The Application Server web application runtime DD is named sun-web.xml and is located in the WEB-INF directory"* If the `sun-web.xml` file does not exist you'll have to create it.  Not all tools will automatically generate files that are specific to specific container vendors.

Comment: what is the exact name of the tag? `context-root`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, context root is the same as package name.

If you use wildfly or jboss, you can add jboss-web.xml to `webapp/WEB-INF/` to change context root, content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>yourownroot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: So there is a `pom.xml` in the root directory of the project, and in that file, there is a `<name>websocketbot</name>` tag enclosed within the outer `<project>` tag along with some other tag, is that the package name you are referring to?

Comment: `<artifactId>` stands for package name. It's usually the same as your project name. So if you want your context root not the same as project name. jboss-web.xml is a better way. `name` you mentioned is for html page title for visitors.